# Skeleton Smoothing not working properly

Tags: c++, filter, kinect

I have to apply smoothing over the skeleton Joints. I have used Joint Filtering proposed at [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/045b058a-ae3a-4d01-beb6-b756631b4b42/joint-smoothing-code?forum=kinectv2sdk), but it is not giving correct result. Is there is any other filter or anyother way to apply the smoothing to the Skeleton?

For example: I have passed all Kinect Joints to the `Update` function on 
KinectJointFilter.cpp (which I got from the above link). But the same data 
are coming as output. I don't feel any change in skeleton smoothing.

Please tell me whether my implementation is correct or not.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to know that unless you post some code.

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: I am using Kinect For Windows V2 , SDK Version is v2.0_1410

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to call the `Init()` method with different smoothing parameters, just after the initialization.

```
FilterDoubleExponential fde = new FilterDoubleExponential();

FLOAT fSmoothing = 0.7f;
FLOAT fCorrection = 0.3f;
FLOAT fPrediction = 1.0f;
FLOAT fJitterRadius = 1.0f;
FLOAT fMaxDeviationRadius = 1.0f;

// The above parameters provide very smoothed joints,
// but also an high latency.
// Change them as you prefer

// Set transform parameters.
fde.Init(fSmoothing, fCorrection, fPrediction, fJitterRadius, fMaxDeviationRadius);
```

Now, whenever you have a new skeleton, pass it to the `Update()` method and use the `GetFilteredJoints()` in order to obtain the smoothed joints.

I have not tried the above code, but it should work.

You can find some useful combinations of parameter in [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20170710004917/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131024.aspx) (it refers to the SDK 1.8, but the parameters in the example are good also in this case).